# Concatenate different information in an Ontology Data Property

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology

Each time a file is accessed I need to annotate it with the location (lat, long) and time information; To track that at which time and place a file is accessed.

My application is ontology based and so I will need to do it by defining new properties in my ontology.

I am currently doing it by a data Property:

> **fileAccessedLocation**
>
> Domains: File
>   Ranges: string
>
> A comma separated representation of a lat, lon concatenated with Date & Time. e.g. 52.500556, 13.398889_atTime_2014-07-14T08:09:00

In my application with this property I am able to achieve what I was needed.

But as far as ontology is concerned, I am not sure concatenating time and location is the correct way.

if concatenating approach is wrong then how will I relate both time and location to a single file access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use multiple data properties. 
Here is an example in OWL Functional Style syntax:

```
Declaration(Class(prefix:FileAccess))
Declaration(DataProperty(prefix:Latitude))
Declaration(DataProperty(prefix:Longitude))
Declaration(DataProperty(prefix:AccessTime))
FunctionalDataProperty(prefix:Latitude)
FunctionalDataProperty(prefix:Longitude)
FunctionalDataProperty(prefix:AccessTime)
DataPropertyRange(prefix:Latitude xsd:double)
DataPropertyRange(prefix:Longitude xsd:double)
DataPropertyRange(prefix:AccessTimexsd:dateTime)
SubClassOf(DataSomeValuesFrom(prefix:Latitude rdfs:Literal) prefix:FileAccess)
SubClassOf(DataSomeValuesFrom(prefix:Longitude rdfs:Literal) prefix:FileAccess)
SubClassOf(DataSomeValuesFrom(prefix:AccessTime rdfs:Literal) prefix:FileAccess)
```

You can try to see the problem from another perspective. Suppose that you have, instead of an ontology, a ER diagram with Entity: `FileAccess`; is it convenient to store multiple information (latitude, longitude and datetime) in a single attribute of this Entity? If you do so, what happens if I want to retrieve from the generated database all the `FileAccess` instances whose datetime is between a given range? The answer is simple, you can't execute a query on the datasource and retrieve the desired records without introducing some more computation which is needed to separate the data you stored in the single attribute by concatenating strings. So, for instance, you need to concatenate strings to store them inside a single attribute, and then you need to split such string to be able to use single components of your "aggregate attribute". Not to mention that after tokenizing your aggregate attribute you need to convert each token to the appropriate datatype.

From an ontology perspective the problem is analogous. Data Properties are attributes, and so binary relations between objects and values, whose domain is a concept (class) and whose range is a value-domain (datatype). This is not valid just for OWL but in general for Description Logics.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please tell me that the way I am doing is wrong or right?

Comment: I edited my post adding further explanations that should let you understand why your approach is not correct, even if it does work.

Comment: Thanks. I followed the same approach you recommended. Problem solved. But one more question is that, as you recommended class for "FileAccess", so on every file access an object of "FileAccess" will be created.So there will be hundreds of objects for a single file. Will it halt my application as far as reasoning and processing are concerened?

Comment: I don't see why. What you are doing here is OBDA I presume, so ontology reasoning is done at TBox/ABox level, while real data are accessed from data sources (I presume you are using some sort of mapping systems that maps your ontology predicates over data sources).